# Unable to upgrade Server 2012 Evaluation to Datacenter

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows, windows-server-2012-r2, upgrade, licensing

I have 
`Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter Evaluation` installed. Validity is only left for 16 days so I thought to upgrade. I have MS subscription so I got the product keys required. I have tried to the keys for the following with no luck:

1. `Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter (Retail)`
2. `Windows 2012 Datacenter (Retail)`
3. `Windows 2012 Standard (Retail)`

   DISM /online /Set-Edition:ServerDatacenterEval /ProductKey:XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX /AcceptEula command

I am getting the following error:

Error: 50

```
This Windows image cannot upgrade to the edition of Windows that was specified.
The upgrade cannot proceed.
Run the /Get-TargetEditions option to see what edition of Windows you can upgrade to.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Did you run `Run the /Get-TargetEditions`?

Comment: yes, it returns ServerDatacenter

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit old, but for future reference you should have run:

```
DISM /online /Set-Edition:ServerDatacenter /ProductKey:XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX /AcceptEula
```

Using /Set-Edition:ServerDatacenter instead of /Set-Edition:ServerDatacenterEval because you need to convert from an Eval version to a "regular" version.

Reference: [Windows Server 2012 Evaluation to Full Retail Standard License - itadminlife.com](http://www.itadminlife.com/articles/3-windows-server-2012-evaluation-to-full-retail-standard-license)